# How to pass an object inside another object in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I rendered a page with an object called "agency". It is coming from the controller that called the page.
Like this:

```
Agency agency = agencyService.findAgencyByName(name);
agencyOrSchool.addObject("agency", agency);
```

In the page (html) I also have a form that is the object "comment". 
Like this:

```
<form  th:action="@{/saveComment}" method="post">
     <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva seu comentário..." rows="3"></textarea>
     <br>
     <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-info float-right">Post</button>
</form>
```

"comment is an attribute of the object 'Comment' (my Model in Java) that I want to save. 
Here is the main part of the model:

```
public class Comments {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@NotNull @NotEmpty
private String comment;

@NotNull @ManyToOne @JoinColumn (name = "userId")
private  User user;

@NotNull @ManyToOne @JoinColumn (name = "agencyId")
private Agency agency;
```

This is right and could work, however, inside the object 'Comment' in my Java model I have the object 'Agency'. That means in the post I have to pass the 'agency' object (already in the page) inside the object 'Comment'.

How can I do it? I tried a lot of things, including this:

```
 <form  th:action="@{/saveComment}" method="post">
                    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva seu comentário..." rows="3"></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" id="user" name="agency" th:object="${agency}"></input>

                    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-info float-right">Post</button>
  </form>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can You provide your model class?

Comment: @AritraPaul Yes, I can. I just edited the question and added the model "Comments" where I have the "Agency" in it.